# Dealing with near duplicates using NLP

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, nlp, spacy

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID,Name,year,output
1,Test Level,2021,1
2,Test Lvele,2022,1
2,dummy Inc,2022,1
2,dummy Pvt Inc,2022,1
3,dasho Ltd,2022,1
4,dasho PVT Ltd,2021,0
5,delphi Ltd,2021,1
6,delphi pvt ltd,2021,1

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

My objective is

a) To replace near duplicate strings using a common string.

For example - let's pick couple of strings from `Name` column. We have `dummy Inc` and `dummy Pvt Inc`. These both have to be replaced as `dummy`

I manually prepared a mapping df `map_df` like as below (but can't do this for big data)

```
  Name,correct_name
  Test Level,Test
  Test Lvele,Test
  dummy Inc,dummy
  dummy Pvt Inc,dummy
  dasho Ltd,dasho
  dasho PVT Ltd,dasho
  delphi Ltd,delphi
  delphi pvt ltd,delphi
```

So, I tried the below

```
map_df = map_df.set_index(Name)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].map(map_df) # but this doesn't work and throws error
```

Is creating mapping table the only way or is there any NLP based approach?

I expect my output to be like as below

```
ID,Name,year,output
1,Test,2021,1
2,Test,2022,1
2,dummy,2022,1
2,dummy,2022,1
3,dasho,2022,1
4,dasho,2021,0
5,delphi,2021,1
6,delphi,2021,1
```

Comment: May worth checking out: [dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe)

Comment: @Ipounng - Is it open-source python package or commercial package? Can open-source package support only till 1000 rows?

Comment: It is MIT licensed. https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe/blob/main/LICENSE

Comment: The NLP technique is called *record linkage*, [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/99653/64377) might give you a few pointers. But you should be careful about the design, because it's likely that making it automatic will cause some errors (both false matches and false non-matches). An option is run the matching first, check manually that the results are correct, and then use a dictionary to replace in the data. Also the method can be more or less complex. In general it works better with long strings.